# recursively search and return filepath

Tags: loops, batch-file, search, recursion

I have many thousands of files within a comprehensive but uniform folder and subfolder structure. I have so far solved the problem by inputting the specific folder addresses, but it is to cumbersome to complete.

I want to replace the adresses enclosed in ???? ???? (which naturally are not in the final code) with a loop that recursively search within the structure and return to the sub-dir level. I know that the ???? has to be excluded in the final code. It is coded as a .bat file. The text files are tab-delimited. The folder-name of id and day changes while main and sub are constant.

```
*** Copy ABC files to ABC folder
xcopy ???"c:\main\sub\id\day\ABC_*.txt" "c:\main\sub\id\day\ABCs"??? /y


*** Adding filepath to file
@ECHO OFF
for /R ????"c:\main\sub\id\day\ABCs"???? %%i IN (ABC_*.txt) DO (
ECHO "%%~fni" > "%%~fni".txt
ECHO. >> "%%~fni"
ECHO. >> "%%~fni"
type "%%~fni" >> "%%~fni".txt
del "%%~fni"
ren "%%~fni".txt *.
)

*** Creation of one ABC file and copy of single ABC files to other directory
copy /b ???"c:\main\sub\id\day\ABC_*.txt"??? ???"c:\main\complete\XXXX.txt"???

the XXXX.txt file has to take the name of the folder in path named id


*** Deleting temporary files
@echo off
RD /s /q ????"c:\main\sub\id\day\ABCs"????
```

thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not understanding. Why don't you just use FOR /R on the whole structure? Can you clarify with some examples of folder structures and files? What are you really trying to do (end goal)?

Comment: @hatiw sometimes more nice if you will show what you have and what you need, because you can choose  wrong way

Comment: My endgoal is to find and append all files starting with ABC_1.txt, ABC_2.txt, ABC_3.txt etc from many folders into one. Each file must have its full path name included in the first line of the text file.

Comment: Since I do not want to change original data, I copy the ABC_*.txt files to a new directory from which I include the filename before appending them to one file. After appending them I delete the temporary folder with ABC_*.txt files with the fullpath included in first line. I actually have want I need, but the the method is not usable on larger upcoming work I have to do.